# You have reached your question limit

Tags: discussion, support, questions, post-ban

Sorry for asking a question like this since it was asked multiple times, but I can't figure out why I'm getting banned from asking question.

I have only [two questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7913142/cuong-tran-duc?tab=questions), none of them has negative score and only one deleted question two years ago(no negative score as i remember)
Now when i try to ask question its show me "we are no longer accepting questions from this account".

Does anyone knows what's wrong with my account? it's so bad when I need help but can't make question.I would preciate if someone could tell me the reason

Comment: I'm a little confused too.. both of the questions I see are positively-scored.

Comment: @EJoshuaS yes, I really don't understand why

Comment: Often when I've seen people ask this there are actually more negatively scored deleted questions that they forgot about. (I'm not saying that's necessarily the case here. I can't see your deleted questions.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Our question ban system takes into account deleted questions, of which you have eight... but we don't show users old deleted content which can make understanding bans somewhat confusing. Some of the old questions were low-scoring but your two recent questions are much better received. Keep up the good work!

You shouldn't be question banned at the moment, though you were when you asked this.

Comment: thank so much for your support

Comment: Sure. :) To be clear, I didn't (and can't) unban someone. I can help but I didn't need to in this case. Between when I saw your question and when I answered it, the ban was lifted.

Comment: "ban system takes into account deleted questions" doesn't mean that I shouldn't delete a bad question, right ? or I just keep it

Comment: We don't divulge the full info of what the ban considers. The linked suggested duplicate question has a lot of good information, though, including - "*Additionally, deletion itself counts against questions less than 30 days old when deleted if others have invested time into answering or moderating the question.*" :) Please do read it so you understand how the bans work!

Comment: Catija, [Why is it (is it?) important to make it hard for banned users to check their deleted posts for 6 months (as opposed to 60 days)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330860/165773)

Comment: @gnat (to be clear, the OP's newest deleted question is from 2017, so that wouldn't even help here...) In general, we try to avoid reminding users of when they've failed because it can be disappointing for the person whose post failed but also problematic for the people who participated in closing/deleting the content. This is part of why we don't notify people when their posts are deleted/closed (which I'm not personally a fan of)... I'd like to revisit both of these things and I think that's something that we'll be doing as we invest in Public Q&A moving forward.

Comment: I think my question here is, why do we have to guess and wait until diamond moderator comes and presents the facts about this (do diamond mods have nothing better to do?) Why is it (is it?) important that banned folks could _not_ tell us the facts themselves, like "yeah OK I checked and there are indeed no deleted questions in last 6 months and all you see in my profile is all that I have posted"

Comment: @gnat But the last six months is irrelevant! That's my point. We look at all-time, so telling someone that they have no deleted questions in the last six months doesn't explain why they're banned. *Assuming* people even see that link, sure, it'll reduce the number of people who think they don't have deleted questions, but it's not going to stop it. I guess the question is, would it be enough to just give them a summary (e.g. count of total/closed/deleted questions/answers) without showing them a list of those questions?

Comment: unless I miss something, it's relevant in this case. If we knew that nothing else holds OP from asking besides these two recent visible questions, we could check these, vote as they deserve (up in this case) and know we're done. Why is it important that we wait for diamond moderator instead of checking this with the OP

Comment: @gnat If the OP has dozens of deleted questions that are heavily downvoted from > 6 months ago, knowing that there aren't any in the last six months is not going to do anything.

Comment: I see! That sounds like a plausible explanation, thank you

Comment: This may have been considered many times in the past, but why take account of deleted questions more than six months old at all? Feels like putting a millstone round someone's neck when they've genuinely fixed their approach. People moving from university into employment might well encounter this sort of thing, and that's when building a good relationship with SO is particularly beneficial.

Comment: @MandyShaw if I remember correctly I saw an explanation that older questions contribute less to the ban criteria (the older the less), That is, some kind of a softer form of what you propose is already in place. Assuming that my recollection is correct, this means that for someone who made lots of heavily downvoted questions in the past it will take longer to have these "forgotten by the system" compared to one who made just a few mistakes. This seems fair enough

Comment: Is it better to delete a question to stop receiving more downvotes or take the risk of modifying it and keeping it more 1 more week in the hope of getting upvotes ?